# Merging multiple rows with same ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge

What is the most efficient method to combine multiple rows of values with the same ID in SQL Server?

Original data table `dbo.ProductCategory`:

```
+-----------+----------+------+
| ProductID |  CATID   |  AA  |
+-----------+----------+------+
|  1        | 123      | A    |
|  1        | 412      | B    |
|  2        | 567      | C    |
|  2        | 521      | A    |
|  3        |   2      | D    |
|  3        |   5      | A    |
|  4        |   6      | C    |
|  4        |   8      | E    |
|  4        | 123      | A    |
+----+------+----------+------+
```

And I'm trying to achieve the following result

```
+-----------+----------+------+
| ProductID |  CATID   |  AA  |
+-----------+----------+------+
|  1        | 123,412  | A,B  |
|  2        | 567,521  | C,A  |
|  3        | 2,5      | D,A  |
|  4        | 6,8,123  | C,E,A|
+----+------+----------+------+
```

Comment: Question is a duplication [SQL Server STRING_AGG](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+SERVER+STRING_AGG) for sure

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017+, you can use STRING_AGG

```
select ProductId, STRING_AGG(CATID, ',') as CATID, STRING_AGG(AA, ',') AA
from PC
GROUP BY ProductID
```

Comment: Thanks alot, thats alot more simpler than the other reference i have found!

Comment: If you feel that this answer is useful, please consider to mark it as answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (ProductID INT,  CATID  INT,  AA  CHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT 1 , 123 , 'A' UNION ALL    
SELECT 1 , 412 , 'B' UNION ALL    
SELECT 2 , 567 , 'C' UNION ALL    
SELECT 2 , 521 , 'A' UNION ALL    
SELECT 3 ,   2 , 'D' UNION ALL    
SELECT 3 ,   5 , 'A' UNION ALL    
SELECT 4 ,   6 , 'C' UNION ALL    
SELECT 4 ,   8 , 'E' UNION ALL    
SELECT 4 , 123 , 'A'
```

Using STUFF() In sql server

```
SELECT ProductID,STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', ', CATID) 
                        FROM @Temp i 
                        WHERE i.ProductID = o.ProductID
                FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS CATID
                ,STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', ', AA) 
                        FROM @Temp i 
                        WHERE i.ProductID = o.ProductID
                FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS AA
FROM @Temp o
GROUP BY ProductID
```

Result

```
ProductID   CATID         AA
------------------------------------
1           123, 412     A , B 
2           567, 521     C , A 
3           2, 5         D , A 
4           6, 8, 123    C , E , A
```